# I can't make autoCapitalize to work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom component like below

```
<Input
  value={value}
  style={styles.input}
  secureTextEntry={passwordInput && !this.state.showPassword}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  autoCapitalize={disableAutoCapitalize ? 'none' : 'words'}
  autoCorrect={!disableAutoCorrect}
  editable={!notEditable}
/>
```

But when I try to set autoCapitalize to words it's not working, why?

```
<InputField
  disableAutoCapitalize={false}
  disableAutoCorrect
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working on iOS but not on Android(Galaxy S9), it looks like a react native bug.

Comment: It is. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8932. Even though the issue is closed and locked, it still exists in React Native 0.59.

Comment: See my answer for a fix and also a backstory

Answer (score 1):

`disableAutoCapitalize` is passed in as a prop I assume. 
You should use `this.props.disableAutoCapitalize`.

```html
<Input
  value={value}
  style={styles.input}
  secureTextEntry={passwordInput && !this.state.showPassword}
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  autoCapitalize={this.props.disableAutoCapitalize ? 'none' : 'words'}
  autoCorrect={!disableAutoCorrect}
  editable={!notEditable}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a react native bug that is fixed after 0.61.5.
But in short, remove keyboardType, if possible, then autoCapitaliz will work for you

See these issues for a backstory: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27510
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8932

Comment: Removing keyboardType the breaks autoFill ‍♀️